# MFC - execute code right after dialog is shown (.NET equivalent of Form.Shown)

Tags: windows, mfc, dialog

I'm doing some small changes to C++ MFC project. I'm .NET developer so Windows programming is new to me.

I need to launch some method right after CDialog is completely shown (painted) for the first time, but only once.

How can I do this? In .NET I would handle **Form.Shown** event.

Do I need to handle some message? Which?
Do I need to override some CDialog method?
Or is there no easy way? I'm thinking of handling WM_ACTIVATE and then using a flag to ensure I call another method only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer here: [Waiting until the dialog box is displayed before doing something](https://web.archive.org/web/20190119124649/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060925-02/?p=29603)

```
Short story:
INT_PTR CALLBACK
DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch (uiMsg) {

  case WM_INITDIALOG:
    return TRUE;

  case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED:
    if ((((WINDOWPOS*)lParam)->flags & SWP_SHOWWINDOW) &&
        !g_fShown) {
      g_fShown = TRUE;
      PostMessage(hwnd, WM_APP, 0, 0);
    }
    break;


  case WM_APP:
      MessageBox(hwnd,
                 IsWindowVisible(hwnd) ? TEXT("Visible")
                                       : TEXT("Not Visible"),
                 TEXT("Title"), MB_OK);
      break;

  case WM_CLOSE:
   EndDialog(hwnd, 0);
   break;
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```

If you're using MFC like I am you'll need to map WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED and then use ON_MESSAGE to map WM_APP. See [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/messagehandling2.aspx?fid=789&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

For reference you don't need to override DlgProc to intercept WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED.

```
   ON_WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED()
   ON_MESSAGE(MyCDialog::MY_USER_MSG, OnDialogShown)

void MyCDialog::OnWindowPosChanged(WINDOWPOS *wndpos)
{
   __super::OnWindowPosChanged(wndpos);

   if (!mDialogShown && (wndpos->flags & SWP_SHOWWINDOW)) {
      PostMessage(MY_USER_MSG);
      mDialogShown = true;
   }
}

LRESULT MyCDialog::OnDialogShown(WPARAM, LPARAM)
{
   ...
}
```

You can implement the handling inline instead of posting another message if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I've used a number of times with great success is to use a timer. Set it for 10m0s. It'll only fire after the dialog is shown.

Comment: @Sumrak The link is broken. Can't find a fix on waybackmachine

Answer (score 0):

Hell put the code in OnPaint() and thow a bool m_fullyInitilized in your class.
I like the timer too.. Though I usually go with 100ms. I also move all my initilization code out of the oninit, in these cases.. Just to protect against too much processing in there.